# Automatically register interface to class in autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Project I'm working on, each class has its own interface with the following naming conventions

ClassA.cs : IClassA.cs

ClassB.cs : IClassB.cs
etc

Currently in the bootstrapper for Autofac I am repeatedly putting

```
builder.RegisterType<ClassA>.As<IClassA>();
builder.RegisterType<ClassB>.As<IClassB>();
```

With a few singletons thrown around for good measure.

Is there any way to automate the binding process?  i know it's not a huge amount of extra effort adding the bindings manually, but it'll get worse as time goes on I'm sure.

I've currently got the following in my container

```
builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyClass>().SingleInstance();

var myAss = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(myAss)
   .Where(t => t.IsClass )
   .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().Single(i => 
   ( i.Name.Length == t.Name.Length + 1 ) && 
   ( i.Name == "I" + t.Name)));
```

However looking at the watch window for builder.  It looks as though it may be registering Myclass twice.  Now I may be completely wrong here as I cannot for the life of me find what's actually being registered in builder by the watch window.

If I am wrong please just give me a slap.

Comment: Take a look at auto scanning in the documentation http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html

Comment: Isn't `.AsImplementedInterfaces()` what you are looking for?

Comment: That does handle the As part definitely.  But it doesn't handle the requirement of certain interfaces being registered as singleton.  I had looked at the ACTNAR thing, but can't see whether it's registering the class to itself, or its interface.  And if it's only to itself, can't see any way to make it register to the interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However looking at the watch window for builder. It looks as though it may be registering Myclass twice.

Yes this is true, since you are registering the class `MyClass` manually as singleton (first line) and a second time in the `RegisterAssemblyTypes` call.

I think registering all your classes this way is pretty risky, since it will fail every time you have a class without an implemented interface or if the interface does not follow your naming convention. Doing something like

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(myAss)
   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
   .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

as shown in the [Autofac docs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html) will probably be more robust. And if you simply want to register all your classes you can skip the `Where` part.

Comment: Thanks, the AsImplementedInterfaces bit is definitely better than what I had been doing.  But not sure if this addresses the issue of having a certain number of singleton instances, as, with this implementation only, they wouldn't be registered as singletons, and adding a separate register above still resutls in the class being registered twice.

Comment: Looking through the doumentation online, it looks like the only way to keep it somewhat safe with the singleton instances is to perform them first and then add  .PreserveExistingDefaults(); after the AsImplementedInterfaces

Comment: @user3265613, Yes using `PreserveExistingDefaults` should work fine, as long as the registrations are equal. If your `MyClass` implements another interface that you didn't register explicitly while registering your singleton, there will be another registration of your `MyClass` class for this second interface because of the `AsImplementedInterfaces` call.